# Efficent url redirection in php

Tags: php, html, redirect

I am using a url redirection technique similar to google

Example

if you type **wikipedia** in google you get a wikpedia page result but if you click the link it will first go to this kind of redirecting link

```
http://www.google.com/url?some_paramaeters_for_wikipedia_page_redirection
```

and then it will go to

```
http://www.wikipedia.org/
```

i have made similar algorithm in my website and its working properly;But as in google when you want to copy the link location

[image]

it doesnt copy the main web link

```
http://www.wikipedia.org/
```

Instead it copies

```
http://www.google.com/url?some_paramaeters_for_wikipedia_page_redirection
```

I want to know if it is possible for users to copy the orginal link instead of url redirecting link without changing redirecting method.

Thanks for your info

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you should do is keep the real link in the `href` attribute (so the "Copy link location" works), 
and with a bit of Javascript, on the click event of your link, replace this real URL with your redirecting one's.